# Algorithm to find the shortest path in a matrix

Tags: c#, algorithm, matrix, path, lua

I tried to find an algorithm for the following problem, but I couldn't.

you have a matrix, 10X6 if it matters. (10 on x dimension 6 on y dimension).
the algorithm receives 2 point, the opening point and the target point.
the array is full of 0's and 1's and it should find the shortest path of 1's between them, and return the first point in this path (the next point in the way to the target).
But here's the catch:

each point can get the value only of the following points:

1. the point above it.
2. the point underneath it.
3. the point left to it.
4. the point right to it.

and to make things even harder: for every point, the value of other point may be different. for example:

1. the opening point is 0,0. the value of 0,1 is 1;
2. the opening point is 0,2. the value of 0,1 is 0.

I can calculate the value so it shouldn't matter for you...
So I thought the only way to solve it is with recursion because of the last condition but if you find another way, you're welcome.

The solution should be in **LUA**, **C#** or **JAVA**.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Removed `[java]` as you stated you don't want Java.

Comment: actually I don't care if you solve it in java and i'll transform it myself to another language ^_^ and I don't have a code because I only tried to find the algorithm itself before actually writing it.

Comment: Even with your restrictions, shouldn't Dijkstra's algorithm still work?

Comment: Then perhaps `language-agnostic` would have been a better tag

Comment: ummm not for sure because I can use only c# java and lua, and for Dikstra's algorithm- I'll look for it and see.

Comment: @user3050072 it's `Dijkstra's`. It's a silent j ^.^

Comment: anyways I would love to see implementation of any algorithm (whether if it is dijkstra's or another one) on my problem. thanks :)

Comment: @user3050072 OR, you could try to implement it. When you run into problems, then post here and tell us what you tried and why it won't work. Until you can show a little bit of effort, I'm voting to close this. Will retract/cast reopen upon a constructive edit

Comment: try searching up graph traversals for shortest paths. This is a good starting point : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm

Comment: but the distance between any two neighbor points (above,beneath,left,and right) is equal. So how does the algorithm "chooses" the next point? just tries all of them? wouldn't the runtime be too long?

Comment: and if it HAS to be in a recursion it would be even more problematic. If someone could help me.. :\

Comment: 10*6 is a relative small matrix. I would have done a BFS (with 4-connected components) and stored the length to each cell from start point in an equal sized array. When you reach the target point, just follow the path of the smallest value back to start. This is a non-recursive solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply interpret your matrix as a graph.  Every cell (i,j) corresponds to a node v(i,j) and two nodes are connected if an only if their corresponding cells are neighbors and both are set to 1.

The example matrix below has the four vertices v(0,0), v(0,1), v(1,0), and v(1,1), with edges {v(0,0),v(0,1)} and {v(0,1),v(1,1)} (the vertex v(1,0) is isolated).

```
1 1
0 1
```

As your graph is unweighted, you can simply use a breadth-first search (BFS) to find a shortest path.  For pseudocode see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Pseudocode

Your restriction that every entry in a matrix only knows its neighboring entries does not matter.  When talking about graphs, this means that ever vertex knows its neighbors, which is exactly what you need in the BFS.  Using a different graph when searching from different starting points does not make the problem harder either.

Just two comments to the poseudocode linked above:

1. It only checks whether there is a connection or not.  If you actually want to have the shortest path, you need to change the following.  When a new vertex u is added to the queue when seen from its neighbor t, you have to store a link at u pointing to t.  When you finally found your target, following back the links gives you the shortest path.
2. Using a set to store which elements are already visited is inefficient.  In your case, just use a boolean matrix of the same size as your input matrix to mark vertices visited.

Comment: The queue ensures that you always consider the nearest vertices first. This is necessary to make sure that you already found the shortest path to a node when you first visit it. Are there any reasons why you do not want to use a queue?

Comment: i just need to implement queue myself in LUA. thanks anyway, and it will find the shortest way because when it gets to this point the algorithm will stop? (so the fastest way is the only way found). just wanted to make sure I understand. (sorry if I'm not clear)

Comment: Yes, as your graph is undirected, all paths you find are shortest paths. Implementing the queue should not be so hard (you do not need a priority queue, just a simple queue).  See for example here: http://www.lua.org/pil/11.4.html

Comment: yes, I already implemented the queue. thanks for everything! I'll set your answer as accepted after I finish.